# Hausdorff dimension of a product

Tags: measure-theory

Given $E \subset \mathbb{R}, F \subset \mathbb{R}$ and that $\dim_HF=\dim_HE=0$. Need to show that $\dim_H(E\times F) \leq 1 $ . 
It just follows from a general result if $F$ is bounded but how do I show it if it is not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boundedness shouldn't be an issue.  If $F$ is unbounded, take $F_N = F \cap [-N,N]$ so $E \times F = \bigcup_{N=1}^\infty E \times F_N$.  A countable union of sets of Hausdorff dimension $0$ has Hausdorff dimension $0$.